# cannot start fwupd-refresh service

Tags: server, 20.04, 22.04, fwupd

I have this service in a failed status on multiple ubuntu 20 and 22 servers, which is annoying because it's triggering warnings on my monitoring system.

I can't start the service, this is `journalctl -xe` when I try to start it:

```
Jun 26 15:03:39 w03 systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
-- Subject: A start job for unit fwupd-refresh.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit fwupd-refresh.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 11102154.
Jun 26 15:03:39 w03 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit fwupd-refresh.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jun 26 15:03:39 w03 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit fwupd-refresh.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 26 15:03:39 w03 systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
-- Subject: A start job for unit fwupd-refresh.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit fwupd-refresh.service has finished with a failure.
```

This is `service fwupd-refresh status`:

```
● fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fwupd-refresh.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-06-26 15:03:39 UTC; 1min 47s ago
TriggeredBy: ● fwupd-refresh.timer
       Docs: man:fwupdmgr(1)
    Process: 287257 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 287257 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 26 15:03:39 w03 systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Jun 26 15:03:39 w03 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 26 15:03:39 w03 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 26 15:03:39 w03 systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
```

I don't know where to find more logs to understand the issue, any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/2532#issuecomment-759096196 dev service with abandond updates by dev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the file under

```
/lib/systemd/system/fwupd-refresh.service
```

Add User=root, and this resolved the service failing.

Then:

```
systemctl daemon-reload; service fwupd-refresh restart; service fwupd-refresh status
```

**This is an example of the service file.**

```
[Unit]
Description=Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
Documentation=man:fwupdmgr(1)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
CacheDirectory=fwupdmgr
StandardError=null
DynamicUser=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_NETLINK AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6
SystemCallFilter=~@mount
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
SuccessExitStatus=2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh
```

Comment: I have changed to user=root, but error persists. Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.

Comment: @Mahler Remember User=root need to be with capital "U".

I have posted the full server file as example.

Comment: I checked it is capital 'U'.

Comment: [Unit]
Description=Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
Documentation=man:fwupdmgr(1)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
CacheDirectory=fwupdmgr
StandardError=null
ProtectSystem=strict
ProtectHome=read-only
User=root
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_NETLINK AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6
SystemCallFilter=~@mount
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
SuccessExitStatus=2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh